# Will IPV6 still follow dotted decimal notation?

Tags: ipv6

I am researching how to handle IPV6 addresses in our system. Will it still use the dotted decimal notation that we had in IPV4? So 127.0.0.1 will still be valid in ipv6?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: The usage of "will" in your question seems to suggest that IPv6 will come some time in the future. That's a wrong assumption. IPv6 has already been standardized for years.

Answer (score 3):

An IPv6 address can end in a dotted IPv4 address part.

That can be helpful for IPv6-embedded IPv4 addresses (such as `::169.254.123.231` instead of `::a9fe:7be7` or  `::ffff:169.254.123.231` instead of `::ffff:a9fe:7be7`), but also for implementing a tunneling mechanism which does the same embedding.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will NOT be valid. The length of an IPv6 address is 128 bits. The length of an IPv4 address is 32 bits in IPv4.

What does this mean?

The usual representation of IPv4 is currently xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Each triplet of digits represents 8 bits or 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 combinations. (That's why IPv4s are 000.000.000.000 - 255.255.255.255)

8*4 triplets = 32 bits address space that an IPv4 address has.

IPv6 addresses on the other hand will have 128 bits and will usually be denoted in hexadecimal quadruplets. (xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx) and since each hexadecimal number contains 4 bits (2<sup>4</sup> = 16 possible combinations), each quadruplet will contain 16 bits. There will be eight quadruplets (16 * 8 = 128 bits), making it a 32 "hexadecimal" digits notation.

Cheers,